Reasons and potential solutions for poor performance of elastic net penalized quantile regression
I'm performing elastic net penalized quantile regression (EN-QR) using the rqPen package on my dataset, which has 6,782 rows and 227 columns (i.e., predictors). 195 of the predictors are metabolites, and my goal is to find out which metabolites are associated with exposure to PM2.5, an air pollutant. I chose to do QR instead of linear regression since PM2.5 data are skewed and not normally distributed, even after performing log-transformation and standardization. I did a 70:30 split of the dataset into the training set (n = 4,747) and testing set (n = 2,035), respectively.
The issue I'm having is that when I apply the EN-QR object from the training set to the testing set to predict PM2.5 values (bottom panel), I get a strange multimodal distribution that doesn't fit the actual PM2.5 values from the testing set (top panel). I have attached a screenshot of these distributions below.

I wonder if anyone has suggestions for troubleshooting this. What are some potential reasons the model would split into a multimodal distribution rather than an (approximately) normal one? Is there something I'm not considering to include in the training set model? Are there any alternative strategies I should look into to achieve my goal of variable selection? Ideally, I'd love to get the EN-QR model to work as it provides the most information for my research question.
I have tried to split the data into four clusters based on which mode of the multimodal distribution they fell into. I found a relationship between the U.S. census region and the modes of the predicted PM2.5 values. For example, almost everyone in the mode with the lowest z score was from the South, and nearly everyone from the highest z score mode was from the Midwest. I find this odd since the U.S. census region was included as a covariate, so the model shouldn't stratify by region. I attached this image and table below.

Here's the R code I used to perform the EN-QR on the training set. Below that is the code I used to predict the PM2.5 values in the testing set.
trainingset.ENQR <- rq.pen.cv(
  x = as.matrix(trainingset[, c(4:5, 27, 29:251)]),
  y = trainingset[, 18],
  tau = c(0.1, 0.5, 0.9),
  penalty = "ENet",
  a = c(0.50, 0.75, 0.90),
  nfolds = 10,
  printProgress = TRUE,
  penalty.factor = c(rep(0, 32), rep(1, 194))
)

lambda.min.training <- trainingset.ENQR$gtr$lambda1se[2]

testingset.ENQR.50 <- rqPen:::predict.rq.pen.seq.cv(object = trainingset.ENQR,
                                     newx = as.matrix(testingset[, c(4:5, 27, 29:251)]),
                                     tau = 0.50,
                                     a = 0.50,
                                     lambda = lambda.min.training,
                                     cvmin = FALSE)


Welcome to Cross Validated! Two quick thoughts. First, it seems like PM2.5 should be the predictor of the metabolites (as outcomes) rather than the other way around. Much transcriptomics, proteomics, and metabolomics works in that direction. Please edit the question to say more about your choice of modeling direction. Second, if you do want to use PM2.5 as the outcome variable then the values themselves don't need to have a normal distribution. It's good to have a normal distribution of the errors around predicted values, but even that might not be necessary if the data set is large.

Thanks EdM! My goal is to perform variable selection on the 195 metabolites to identify those associated with PM2.5 exposure (and drop metabolites not associated with PM2.5). While it is true that many 'omics studies model exposures as predictors of individual 'omic variables (e.g., metabolites) to investigate the biological response to an exposure, this isn't my objective. Instead, I want to identify metabolites most strongly associated with PM2.5 to facilitate further exploration of these metabolites' roles in mediating downstream health outcomes. I appreciate your comment on the residuals!

To my mind, at least, if you want "to identify metabolites most strongly associated with PM2.5," the most logical way is to use PM2.5 as a predictor variable in a multivariate (multiple-outcome) model. It's hard to argue that a change in a metabolite level could affect a PM2.5 value, but that's what you are implicitly implying in the way that you set up this model.* A multivariate model with PM2.5 as a predictor (ideally modeled flexibly, maybe with a spline, maybe after some transformation, maybe with other demographic information as predictors associated with metabolite levels) and metabolites as outcomes will identify metabolites "strongly associated with PM2.5" that are worthy of investigation for "roles in mediating downstream health outcomes."
Tools like those in the Bioconductor limma package can be used to identify the top hits most closely associated with predictors in a multivariate regression model, along with corresponding false-discovery rates. Although limma was originally devised for microarray transcriptomics, its tools have since found widespread use in RNA-seq transcriptomics, proteomics, and metabolomics. Such tools provide a well established way to identify initial candidates for downstream studies in biomedical research.
If you nevertheless want to use PM2.5 as the outcome, you might be making a mistake in jumping so quickly to quantile regression. It doesn't matter that the PM2.5 values have a skewed, multi-modal distribution. If skew and multi-modality in an outcome variable is associated with skew and multi-modality of predictor variables, linear regression could be a very useful choice.
This page and its links go through the assumptions of ordinary least squares regression. What might matter is whether the distribution of errors around model predictions has a normal distribution. With a large enough data set, even that isn't necessary if the errors are homoscedastic (same distribution along the range of predicted values), as what really matters is the normal distribution of coefficient estimates. And even if you don't have homoscedastic errors, there are ways to deal with that.
With respect to the multimodality of the predicted values: if you have a good model of a multimodal outcome variable, you would hope that the predictions would also be multimodal.
With respect to the compression of the vertical axis between the observed and predicted PM2.5 distributions: that's why it's called regression. Predicted values from a regression cannot have as wide a range as the original values, unless the model fits extremely well. The extreme values are "regressed toward the mean" in the predictions.

*I understand that a regression only finds associations, so one might argue that your approach is OK. I do think that it might be hard to convince a reviewer, however, when a direct approach more consistent with a causal chain is available.
